# Promise chain breaking

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have a promise chain (bluebird) that breaks up, and I can't figure out why.

```
 Promise.resolve()
   .then(function() {
     [..]
   })
   .then(function() {
     [..]
   })
   .then(function() {
     [..]
   })
   .spread(function(instance) {
     [..]
   })
```

This fails with `TypeError: undefined is not a function` on [`.spread`](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#spreadfunction-fulfilledhandler--function-rejectedhandler----promise). A `console.log` on the last `.then()` show it returns `{}`. Exchanging `spread` for `then` makes the code run. What am I doing wrong? What would make spread be undefined?

---

Update: Changing the last `spread` to the code below makes it work.

```
   .then(function(arr) {
     var instance = arr[0];
     [..]
   })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot :) missed including bluebird in that file, so it was using the [native implementation of promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) which doesn't have `spread`.